# Dynamically Add in jQuery Mobile Attributes

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, dynamic, attributes

I am adding in jQuery mobile attributes dynamically. I have had luck with some of them. However I can't seem to figure out how to add in data-type="horizontal" properly.

This code works perfectly:

```
$("form, fieldset, #info_list").collapsible();
$("#color_group, #animal_group").controlgroup();
```

I want #color_group & #animal_group to have the attribute data-type="horizontal". I couldn't find any methods like the ones for controlgroup & collapsible, though; so I tried this:

```
$("#color_group, #animal_group").attr("data-type", "horizontal");
```

This adds the attribute, however using this method jQuery mobile does nothing with it when it's added in this way.

Comment: which jQM version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/k9Pnd/)**

the controlgroup widget has a 'type' option you can set to horizontal (http://api.jquerymobile.com/controlgroup/)

```
$("#color_group, #animal_group").controlgroup({ type: "horizontal" });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.controlgroup({ type: "horizontal" })` or `"vertical"` to change type, not `data-type`.

```
$("controlgroup_ID").controlgroup({
    type: "horizontal"
});

$("controlgroup_ID").controlgroup({
    type: "vertical"
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/6eqmL/)**

Comment: looks like we answered at the same time @Omar. plus 1

Comment: @ezanker you were seconds faster than me, +1 to you ;) have you checked my update on content height?

Comment: @Omar I did not see it. Great find, see my comment there and let me know what you think.